# How do I select the text area using cheerio in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, cheerio

**Example:**

```
<div class="A">
    I'm in A.
    <h1 class="B">
           I'm in A and B.          
    </h1>
    I'm in A, too.
</div>
```

If I use `$('div.A').text()` to select, I will also get `I'm in A and B`. But I just want to get `I'm in A` and `I'm in A, too`. How do I select the part I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead, of using `.text`, use `.contents` to get all of the nodes (including text nodes), then use `each` to loop through them and only get the text of the text nodes:

```
var text = [];
$("div.A").contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3) { // 3 = Text node
        text.push(this.nodeValue);
    }
});

console.log(text); // ["I'm in A.", "I'm in A, too."]
```

*(Actual logged contents will likely have whitespace around them as that whitespace is in the text node, depending on the exact markup.)*

Or if you prefer:

```
var text = $("div.A")
    .contents()
    .filter(function() {
        return this.nodeType === 3; // 3 = Text node
    })
    .map(function() {
        return this.nodeValue;
    })
    .get();
```

Which looks a lot tidier in ES2015+:

```
let text = $("div.A")
    .contents()
    .filter((i, e) => e.nodeType === 3)
    .map((i, e) => e.nodeValue)
    .get();
```

Answer (score 2):

This simple trick would help get what you want.

```
$('div.A')
    .clone()    //clone the element
    .children() //select all the children
    .remove()   //remove all the children
    .end()  //again go back to selected element
    .text();
```

Its based on the clone method, you can read more about it [from here](https://api.jquery.com/clone/).

```
$('div.A').clone().children().remove().end().text() //single line representation
```